# VisualStudio 2022 React+Asp.Net в импорте включить Itellisense для файлов в папке (scss css и др.))

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, visual-studio-2022, intellisense

Мне надо в файлах .jsx(.js) при написании import './' чтоб здесь появлялась подсказка о всех файлах в папке как это работает в VS Code.
Я раньше нашел решение на оверах, но теперь снова не могу вспомнить и найти.
Кажется там надо добавить файл jsconfig.json с параметрами.
Пробовал, но файлы scss и css не высвечивает в подсказке.